# Manipulate Data SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to manipulate a piece if data I am pulling in. Right now the name is pulling in as `First Name Last Name` I would like to pull it in as `Last Name, First Name`.

Query

```
SELECT name from [TBL_Customers] order by name
```

The `name` column has the first and last name contained in it, with a space separating the two.

What is the best practice to achieve `Last Name, First Name`?

Comment: `"What is the best practice"` - Honestly, the "best practice" is to treat single values as single values and multiple values as multiple values.  If a "name" should have two distinct parts, store it in two distinct columns.  Parsing names from a single string value is a non-trivial task.  What are you going to do with names which contain more than 2 parts?  Or where any given part itself has a space in it?  Also, an obligatory link: http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: possible duplicate of [T-SQL substring - separating first and last name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10921400/t-sql-substring-separating-first-and-last-name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply use SQL Server's built in `substring`, `charindex` and `left` functions to do this:

```
SELECT NAME
      ,substring(NAME, charindex(' ', NAME) + 1, LEN(NAME) - CHARINDEX(' ', NAME) + 1) 
       + ', ' + left(NAME, charindex(' ', NAME) - 1) as new_name
FROM TBL_Customers
order by name;
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5b525/1/0)